# How to connect an ethernet device with an AP and reach the AP's client's from the ethernet's client?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ip, networkmanager, wifi-hotspot

I'm configuring a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W to act as a IOT hacking/development bridge.

**The Primary goals of this are:**

- Maintain a managed client wlan device to download packages or connect to a device's ad hoc wireless network.
- Provide a wireless network for the IOT device to connect to, but without internet access to isolate it.
- Power + network with the pi over a single USB wire via  USB Ethernet gadget mode
- Interact with the IOT device from the development machine powering the pi/ethernet gadget.

**what I have so far**

1- The USB ethernet gadget configured with a static IP via two lines in `/etc/rc.local`

```
ip addr add 10.20.20.1/24 dev usb0
ip link set dev usb0 up
```

2-  The AP and Managed network co-mingling well. This was done by connecting to the wifi network with `nmcli device wifi connect <myhomenetwork> password <homenetworkpw>`. Once that was connected, a udev rule was used to create a second virtual wireless interface via:

```
#70-persistent-net.rule
#note phy0 mac *:87 and the new virtual dev mac *:89
SUBSYSTEM=="ieee80211", ACTION=="add|change", ATTR{macaddress}=="d8:3a:dd:ba:6d:87", KERNEL=="phy0", \
  RUN+="/sbin/iw phy phy0 interface add ap0 type __ap", \
  RUN+="/bin/ip link set ap0 address d8:3a:dd:ba:6d:89"
```

This provided me with the interface, which was then configured with the following nmcli commands

```
#!/bin/bash
nmcli con delete dev_ap
nmcli con add type wifi ifname ap0 mode ap con-name dev_ap ssid Special_ssid autoconnect true
nmcli con modify dev_ap 802-11-wireless.band bg
nmcli con modify dev_ap 802-11-wireless.channel 3
nmcli con modify dev_ap 802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address d8:3a:dd:ba:6d:89
nmcli con modify dev_ap ipv4.method shared ipv4.address 10.20.10.1/24
nmcli con modify dev_ap ipv4.never-default yes
nmcli con modify dev_ap ipv6.method disabled
nmcli con modify dev_ap wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
nmcli con modify dev_ap wifi-sec.psk "awesomepassword"
nmcli con up dev_ap
```

3- A firewall to prevent peeping IOT devices

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i ap0 -o wlan0 -j DROP
```

**What does this get me?**

This leaves me with a wifi connection that works as you'd expect, an access point with dhcp that cannot reach the internet, but can reach the pi, and a new USB ethernet interface on my dev machine. I can set my dev machine's static ip on that interface to an address in the subnet, and SSH into the pi.

ip a reports:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 62:f4:4e:bf:3c:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.20.1/24 scope global usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::60f4:4eff:febf:3c56/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:ba:6d:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.145/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 5761sec preferred_lft 5761sec
    inet6 fe80::1e9f:328e:dbe0:abda/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:ba:6d:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr d8:3a:dd:ba:6d:87
    inet 10.20.10.1/24 brd 10.20.10.255 scope global noprefixroute ap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**What am I missing?**

Right now, a client of `ap0` can ping the dev machine connected to `usb0`, but the dev machine cannot ping a client of `ap0`.

**extra info**

Here's the output of `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.145 metric 601 
10.20.10.0/24 dev ap0 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.10.1 metric 600 
10.20.20.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.20.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.145 metric 601
```

result of `nft list ruleset`

```
table ip nm-shared-ap0 {
        chain nat_postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 10.20.10.0/24 ip daddr != 10.20.10.0/24 masquerade
        }

        chain filter_forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                ip daddr 10.20.10.0/24 oifname "ap0" ct state { established, related } accept
                ip saddr 10.20.10.0/24 iifname "ap0" accept
                iifname "ap0" oifname "ap0" accept
                iifname "ap0" reject
                oifname "ap0" reject
        }
}
table ip filter {
        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "ap0" oifname "wlan0" counter packets 11692 bytes 763264 drop
        }
}
```

`iftables-save -c`

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 (nf_tables) on Wed Jan 31 03:33:00 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
[11794:770312] -A FORWARD -i ap0 -o wlan0 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jan 31 03:33:00 2024
```

Comment: When a system can ping an other but not the opposite, usually that means routing is ok and that there's firewalling or NAT in the way. Can you provide all the firewall rules? If handled with iptables: `iptables-save -c`. If previous doesn't give more than the added FORWARD rule, maybe it's handled with nftables: `nft list ruleset`. Also the title talks about bridging. This has a very specific meaning in networking, but nothing beside the title suggests bridging is wanted or needed. What do you mean with "bridge"?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I was at a loss for the right word. 

I added the results of nft list ruleset and iptables-save, its my first time looking at the former. I can't tell if it would cause a block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there are *nftables* rules allowing only the right sources from `ap0` to itself or to outside (which is then dropped by the additional *iptables-nft* rule when using `wlan0`).

In particular this rule in `filter_forward`:

> ```
> oifname "ap0" reject
> ```

prevents routed traffic originally initiated from elsewhere to reach `ap0`.

The table name starting with `nm-shared` was automatically created by NetworkManager settings, because of `ipv4.method shared` mode:

> ```
> nmcli con modify dev_ap ipv4.method shared ipv4.address 10.20.10.1/24
> ```

Once in place, if it allows tampering (there are provisions in the future to prevent an *nftables* table to be changed by something else than the daemon controlling it), then this command run as *root* user will immediately allow traffic initiated from `usb0` to `ap0`:

```
nft insert rule ip nm-shared-ap0 filter_forward index 3 iifname usb0 oifname ap0 accept
```

This will be reverted as soon as NetworkManager rewrites the rules for any reason (but already ongoing connections such as an established SSH connection should still be able to continue working).

---

Anything more durable requires changing NetworkManager settings. From the [NetworkManager blog documenting this feature](https://networkmanager.dev/blog/networkmanager-1-32/):

> **Firewall Mode and nftables**
>
> When activating a "shared" profile, NetworkManager will
> enable NAT for IPv4. Until now, it could only call `iptables` to
> configure masquerading. With this new version, it can also configure
> nftables for the same purpose. The firewall backend can be configured
> via the new `[main].firewall-backend` option in [NetworkManager.conf](https://networkmanager.pages.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf.html). In
> absence of an explicit configuration the default is
> "nftables" unless `/usr/sbin/nft` does not exist and
> `/usr/sbin/iptables` exists.

The [`NetworkManager.conf`](https://networkmanager.pages.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf.html) link tells:

> `firewall-backend`
>
> The firewall backend for configuring masquerading with shared mode.
> Set to either `iptables`, `nftables` or `none`. `iptables` and `nftables`
> require `iptables` and `nft` application, respectively. **`none` means to skip
> firewall configuration if the users wish to manage firewall
> themselves.** If unspecified, it will be auto detected.

The easiest for this case is to disable the use of a firewall backend and then if needed implement rules manually as OP already did here using *iptables*, or else using *nftables*. To disable NetworkManager's firewall, edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and add an entry under the `[main]` block (keep any other entries already present in this block and any other blocks) so it will start at least like:

```ini
[main]
firewall-backend=none
```

and restart NetworkManager (or reboot).

---

Should later traffic from `ap0` to Internet be allowed again, it's possible that the main router won't recognize the addresses used from `ap0`. In this case, this could be restored with this *iptables* rule replacing the *nftables* NAT rule:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.20.10.0/24 ! -d 10.20.10.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

If not allowing such traffic, don't bother.

Comment: Thank you so much, the first nft command got the traffic flowing correctly. I completely overlooked nftables and didn't come across the appropriate networkmanager documentation.